# Error with language file in phpbb

Tags: phpbb

I'm trying to restore an old forum but in geting tho following error: 
`Language file ./language//common.php couldn't be opened`.
I cant figure out where this is located and how to restore it if its broken.  Im asking for some help here. The version of phpbb is 2 years old with custom modules inside. Its really hard to change it or upgrade because i dont know how the wesite will behave. Note that i didnt wrote the site. I tried to google this problem but i couldnt find the solution.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you found soloution?.

Answer (score 0):

You are a few characters missing in the URL which denote which language it should be looking in, for example for English you would have `./language/en/common.php`

Comment: thats the problem. it doesnt know which folder should look for the lanuage.